# How do I install sfx files in Debian

Tags: debian, software-installation, gnome, virtual-machine

I want to install a virtual machine, and i need to install a SFX file. I know the command for Ubuntu is `chmod +x filename.sfx` But I don't know the command for Debian. Does any one know?

Please ignore this question... It is a duplicate...

Comment: A sfx file is (usually) a self extracting archive. `chmod` is used here to make it executable, not to "install" it. Then you execute it to extract the content. And `chmod` is available on Debian too.

Comment: @Leiaz
It worked... Put it as the answer so i can give you the credit of solving it...

Comment: There wasn't much to "solve", and there is already an answer posted merely a few seconds later.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The command 'chmod +x filename' does not install anything, it just sets the "executable" attribute on file.

If you write a shell script with the filename 'myscript' and then you do 'chmod +x myscript' then instead of doing 'sh myscript' to run it, you will be able to do so with only 'myscript' (assuming the file is in a directory in your path).

That being said, 'chmod' is a common utility found on virtually every unix(-like) OS out there, and Ubuntu is merely a highly customised version of Debian, which is a distro of Linux, which is a unix clone.